# Want to call ui-sref configured Controller's method instead of current Controller

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router, ui-sref

I am using `ui-sref` for routing.

#### Current View

```
<a ui-sref="home.teamtasklist" ng-click="getTeamMemberTask()">Team Task</a>
```

#### Current Controller

```
$scope.getTeamMemberTask=function(){alert("This is called")};
```

#### App.js

```
 $stateProvider.state('home.teamtasklist', {
  url: "",
  templateUrl : 'assets/view/teamtasklistview.html',
  controller:'TaskController',
})
```

#### TaskController.js

```
$scope.getTeamMemberTask=function(){alert("I want to call this")};
```

I want to call  TaskController's  `getTeamMemberTask`  method instead of Current Controller `getTeamMemberTask` Controller method. How can I acheive this?

Comment: What is the higher level issue here as far as what needs to be acheived? You probably need  to use params in url and pass data to next state through those params

Comment: you should have something to be in `url` to differentiate child route..

Comment: Basically ,I want to ask,is there way to configure ui-sref to decide which method of configured controller to be called. TaskController has many  other method.  Ok so you are saying,I need to inject $stateParams in my controller and decide which method to be called  depending upon choice(param passed)  .Thanks for help